# Using apache to serve a js app and its api

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, api, backbone.js

So while working in localhost, I had the following folder structure

```
/htdocs
    /multikanban      # the js app
    /multikanban-api  # the php api
```

To make requests from the js app to the php api I basically used relative paths.

Now I am trying to deploy this to my dedicated server. I managed to get both projects working under http://multikanban.com (the app) and http://api.multikanban.com (the api). However, making requests from the app to the api requires of CORS as using a subdomain is considered as not part of the domain. I don't want to use CORS because this api will only be consumed by the app. That's why I moved the multikanban-api folder into the multikanban one and tried to use relative paths.

So far, I find problems because of my .htaccess and apache configuration.

The apache config looks like

```
#
#  multikanban.com (/etc/apache2/sites-available/multikanban)
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin mezood@gmail.com
        ServerName  multikanban.com
        ServerAlias www.multikanban.com

        # Indexes + Directory Root.
        # DirectoryIndex /app/index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/multikanban/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

while the .htaccess for the app looks like

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !multikanban-api 
    RewriteRule (.*) app/index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

This is basically the config for backbone's pushstate to work, but I added the RewriteCond to ignore multikanban-api so that the url is not understood as a route of the app.

The problem is that with this config http://multikanban.com/multikanban-api will return a Not Found. I understand this is caused because of DocumentRoot being /multikanban/app and not just /multikanban. That's why I tried to define

```
 DocumentRoot /var/www/multikanban/ 
 DirectoryIndex /app/index.html
```

but that doesn't work at all. Acessing http://multikanban.com returns a require.js SyntaxError and doesn't even load the app.

Any ideas of how can I fix this or a way around on how to access the /multikanban-api without using CORS?

Answer (score 1):

I gave it some more thought, maybe you need to do something like a virtual directory? http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-virtual-directory-apache

```
<IfModule alias_module>
Alias /multikanban-api /htdocs/multikanban-api
</IfModule>
```

Why do you want to avoid CORS?

I don't know in what way your setup isn't working, but pull out all the JavaScript app, just have an HTML page on the main site, with a simple JavaScript AJAX call done inline to the API.

Additionally use something like Postman to verify the API is working as expected.

Basically keep simplifying your stack, stuff like Require might be getting in your way. Get each piece running independently, you might just be trying to pull it all together too soon.

Comment: CORS adds complexity and I don't need it here, because the js app is the only one consuming the api.
The problem is that the api can't be found, I get a not found for multikanban.com/multikanban-api